# ESP32 can't recieve multicast UDP Packet

Tags: udp, esp32, multicast, arduino-esp32

I am trying to let two or more ESP32-S2s communicate from one to the others over udp. Since they possibly dont know each others ip i wanted to use multicast.
Sending MulticastPackets is working.(At least I can wireshark the Packets on my PC).

Recieving on the other esp doesnt work so far.
Im Broadcasting to 192.168.178.255:7777

The reciever uses the following code:

```
//Called once after Wifi is connected:
udp.beginMulticast(OAL_Broadcast, OALPort); // 192.168.178.255, 7777 as inputs

//Called periodically :
Serial.println(udp.parsePacket()); // In my case always returns 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I just tried to use the second/recieving esp as sender and saw that in wireshark the first esp sends from port 7777 to 7777 and the second one from 55355 to 7777. Is it possible, that for some reason the second esp doesnt listen on 7777?

Comment: Another thing that I just realised is that apparently the second esp isnt able to connect to the same wifi reapeater as the other one. Only the one next to it works when the reapeater mis plugged in. Is this a problem if different repeaters are used?

Answer (score 0):

A few things could be happening.

The multicast IP address range is between 224.0.0.0-239.255.255.255 and usually a device joins a multicast group on one of those. Also it might treat sending a multicast more loosely when it comes to the IP address but receiving one it must be within the range of multicast addresses due to how it routes that packet to a multicast group.

If one device is on another network device but still on the same network then it could be ttl related and each network device is treated as a hop. I have seen something like this happen before. You might be able to adjust that on the network device side or on the esp32 side.